# pandas replace (erase) different characters from strings

Tags: python, string, text, pandas, replace

I have a list of high schools. I would like to erase certain characters, words, and symbols from the strings.

I currently have:

```
df['schoolname'] = df['schoolname'].str.replace('high', "")
```

However, I would like to use a list so I can quickly replace `high`, `school`, `/`, etc.

Any suggestions?

```
df['schoolname'] = df['schoolname'].str.replace(['high', 'school'], "")
```

does not work

Comment: Could you just wrap your `replace()` with a for loop?

Comment: @chrisaycock I thought about that but it seemed like a sort of workaround solution. To have to iterate through the whole array x number of times instead of going through it once looking for any of the characters

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use regex (seperate the strings by `|`):

```
df['schoolname'] = df['schoolname'].str.replace('high|school', "")
```

Comment: ohh. hmm. i tried `df['schoolname'] = df['schoolname'].str.replace('high| hig| schools|school|schoo| scho| sch| sc|@|/|-|h s| hs|.|"', "")` however i just ended up with an empty column. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @As3adTintin dot is a special regex character (which catches all), you have to escape it with `\.`

Comment: its faster and more efficient than for loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a dictionary and then [`.replace({}, regex=True)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method:

```
replacements = {
   'schoolname': {
      r'(high|school)': ''}
}

df.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem: I wanted to find a simple solution in deleting characters / symbols using the replace method with pandas.

**I had the following array in a data frame:**

```
  df = array(['2012', '2016', '2011', '2013', '2015', '2017', '2001', '2007',
   '[2005], ©2004.', '2005', '2009', '2008', '2009, c2008.', '2006',
   '2019', '[2003]', '2018', '2012, c2011.', '[2012]', 'c2012.',
   '2014', '2002', 'c2005.', '[2000]', 'c2000.', '2010',
   '2008, c2007.', '2011, c2010.', '2011, ©2002.', 'c2011.', '[2017]',
   'c1996.', '[2018]', '[2019]', '[2011]', '2000', '2000, c1995.',
   '[2004]', '2005, ©2004.', 'c2004.', '[2009]', 'c2009.', '[2014]',
   '1999', '[2010]', 'c2010.', '[2006]', '2007, 2006.', '[2013]',
   'c2001.', 'C2016.', '2008, c2006.', '2011, ©2010.', '2007, c2005.',
   '2009, c2005.', 'c2002.', '[2004], c2003.', '2009, c2007.', '2003',
   '©2003.', '[2016]', '[2001]', '2010, c2001.', '[1998]', 'c1998.'],
  dtype=object)
```

As you can see, the years were entered using multiple formats (ugh!) with brackets and copyright symbols and lowercase c and uppercase C.

Now I wanted to remove those unwanted characters and only have the years in four digits. Since it's an array, you also need to transform it into a string before using replace(). Create a variable of all the characters you want replaced and separate them with ' | '.

```
rep_chars = 'c|C|\]|\[|©|\.'

df[Year] = df['Year'].str.replace(rep_chars,"")
```

> Make sure to use `\.` and not just the period. The same with `\]` and `\[`.

**Output:**

```
array(['2012', '2016', '2011', '2013', '2015', '2017', '2001', '2007',
   '2005, 2004', '2005', '2009', '2008', '2009, 2008', '2006', '2019',
   '2003', '2018', '2012, 2011', '2014', '2002', '2000', '2010',
   '2008, 2007', '2011, 2010', '2011, 2002', '1996', '2000, 1995',
   '2004', '1999', '2007, 2006', '2008, 2006', '2007, 2005',
   '2009, 2005', '2004, 2003', '2009, 2007', '2010, 2001', '1998'],
  dtype=object)
```

Happy Data Cleaning!