# use python to replace multiple words from a dataframe string column

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame 'df' with a string column. I was trying to remove a list of special values from this column.

For example if the column 'number' is: onE1, I want it change to 1; if the column is FOur4, I want it change to 4

I used the following code:

```
for i in ['onE','TwO','ThRee', 'FOur']:
    print(i)
    df['new_number'] = df['number'].str.replace(i,'')
```

Although print(i) shows the i go through the list of strings, the column 'new_number' only removed 'FOur' from column 'number', the rest string 'onE','TwO','ThRee' are still in column 'new_number', which means onE1, is still onE1; but value FOur4 changed to 4 in the column 'new_number'

So what is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: you should show us the content of `df['number']`

Comment: you want to delete the row that contain `'fOur'` ? can you show how is `df` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar post to this question
[pandas replace (erase) different characters from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157643/pandas-replace-erase-different-characters-from-strings)

we can use regex to solve this issue
df['new_number'] = df['number'].str.replace('onE|TwO|ThRee|FOur','')

Answer (score 0):

To get the numbers from the string in the dataFrame you can use this:

```
number = ''.join(x for x in df['number'].str if x.isdigit())
```