# Vectorized str.replace for multiple characters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe:

```
 {'country': {0: 'Afghanistan?*', 1: 'Albania?*'},
 'region': {0: 'Asia', 1: 'Europe'},
 'subregion': {0: 'Southern Asia', 1: 'Southern Europe'},
 'rate_per_1000': {0: 6.7, 1: 2.1},
 'count': {0: '2,474', 1: '61'},
 'year': {0: 2018, 1: 2020},
 'source': {0: 'NSO', 1: 'NSO'}}

          country  region        subregion  rate_per_1000  count  year source
0   Afghanistan?*    Asia    Southern Asia            6.7  2,474  2018    NSO
1       Albania?*  Europe  Southern Europe            2.1     61  2020    NSO
```

There are multiple bad characters here that I want to get rid of. I made a short function for .apply() to get rid of them, however I am looping over a defined list of bad characters. This gives a bad code smell to me, I think this operation could be more vectorized in some way. This is what I've tried:

```
bad_chars = ['?', '*', ',']

def string_cleaner(col):
    if col.dtype == 'object':
        for char in bad_chars:
            col = col.str.replace(f'{char}', '')
        return col

homicide_by_country = homicide_by_country.apply(string_cleaner)
```

```
homicide_by_country
        country  region        subregion rate_per_1000 count  year source
0   Afghanistan    Asia    Southern Asia          None  2474  None    NSO
1       Albania  Europe  Southern Europe          None    61  None    NSO
```

My desired outcome is a more pythonic/pandonic technique for accomplishing the same outcome.

edit: You may notice for some reason my rate_per_1000 columns goes blank. I haven't troubleshot that problem yet but if you spot something obvious I'm all ears.

Comment: I think my count and year columns are breaking because of the if statement excluding those two columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas replace (erase) different characters from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157643/pandas-replace-erase-different-characters-from-strings)

Comment: @ZLi this linked question helps guide, but doesn't answer directly OP's question because of regex complexities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`

```
import re
>>> df.replace('|'.join(map(re.escape, bad_chars)),'', regex=True)
```

Notice that this will keep the same dtypes of your columns, so no need to worry about numeric cols.

Also, note that you need a special treatment of your regex because `?`, `*` etc are special characters in regular expressions, so you need to escape these chars.

---

In more detail, `re.escape` will basically add a `\` in front of every character in `bad_chars`, as long as it's a special character. This is necessary as to make sure that special character is meant literally as is.

Take [this example from the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#repeating-things):

```
The first metacharacter for repeating things that we’ll look at is *. 
* doesn’t match the literal character '*'; 
instead, it specifies that the previous character can be 
matched zero or more times, instead of exactly once.
```

This means that if you just use `df.replace("*", "", regex=True)`, the engine will interpret `*` as a metacharacter, not as an asterisk, which will yield weird results. However, if you do `df.replace("\*", "", regex=True)`, then `*` will be interpreted as an asterisk. "Escaping" means this action of adding a `\` to indicate you mean the literal character.

Now, `|` is also a metacharacter that means "join", or [`"or"`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#compilation-flags). Here, we do NOT want to escape the pipe, because we want it interpreted with its regexp power.

The expression below

```
'|'.join(map(re.escape, bad_chars))
```

will yield something like

```
\?|\*|,
```

which means we want to replace all `\?` and `\*` and `,` with empty strings.

Comment: Could you please explain why you're using '|'.join() here? I tried without but got an error but still can't figure out why it's needed :)

Comment: Perfect answer! Would you mind going into slightly more detail on whats going on here though? Why the '|' and .join()? Also I knew regex could help but I kept getting errors because of the special characters lol

Comment: @Drakax in regular expressions, `|` means "or". So, for example, if you use `replace("a|b", "", regex=True)` you will replace all characters that match `a` or `b` with an empty string. @rengeseeker Sure! Will add more explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select_dtypes` to target your replacement, then `update`:

```
import re
bad_chars = ['?', '*', ',']
reg = f'[{"".join(map(re.escape, bad_chars))}]'
df.update(df
   .select_dtypes(object)
   .apply(lambda c: c.str.replace(reg, '', regex=True))
 )

print(df)
```

*NB. The modification is in place*

Output:

```
       country  region        subregion  rate_per_1000 count  year source
0  Afghanistan    Asia    Southern Asia            6.7  2474  2018    NSO
1      Albania  Europe  Southern Europe            2.1    61  2020    NSO
```

Comment: Why not just `df.replace(reg, '', regex=True)` ? Feels like this could be less verbose :)